# Filter to NOT show out of stock items

Tags: magento-1.9, configurable-product, filter, simple-product

I am using the following code to show my simple products on the configurable and then it sorts by price.

```
if($_product->getTypeId() == "configurable"): ?>
    <?php $conf = Mage::getModel('catalog/product_type_configurable')->setProduct($_product); ?>
    <?php $simple_collection = $conf->getUsedProductCollection()->addAttributeToSelect('*')->addFilterByRequiredOptions()->addAttributeToSort('Price', 'asc'); ?>


<?php   foreach($simple_collection as $simple_product){ ?>
```

I now want to filter to show only items that are in stock, maybe by using this code:`addFilterByRequiredOptions()`

**Is it possible or is there another way**?

Here is the complete file

```
<?php 
$_helper = $this->helper('catalog/output');
$_product = $this->getProduct();
$theme = $this->helper('royal');
$prods = $this->helper('egproducts');
$prodsConfig = $prods->getConfig('prev_next');
$prodId = $_product->getId();
$prevProduct = $prods->getPreviousProduct($prodId, $prodsConfig['list_sort_by'], $prodsConfig['list_sort_dir']);
$nextProduct = $prods->getNextProduct($prodId, $prodsConfig['list_sort_by'], $prodsConfig['list_sort_dir']);
$rightEnabled = $theme->getSetting('product_page/eg_right_column');
$gridClass = "grid-full no-padding";
if ($rightEnabled)
    $gridClass = "grid12-9 no-padding-left-lg no-padding-left-md no-padding-xs no-padding-sm grid-xs-full grid-sm-full";
?>
<?php
if($_product->getTypeId() == "configurable"): ?>
    <?php $conf = Mage::getModel('catalog/product_type_configurable')->setProduct($_product); ?>
    <?php $simple_collection = $conf->getUsedProductCollection()->addAttributeToSelect('*')->addFilterByRequiredOptions()->addAttributeToSort('Price', 'asc'); ?>
<?php   foreach($simple_collection as $simple_product){ ?>
<div id="results">
<div class="mydata">
<table style="border-bottom: 1px solid #D3D3D3;">
some content
</table>
</div>
</div>
<?php
    }
endif;
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### As an alternative solution:

**First get child product ids from configurable**

```
$childIds=Mage::getResourceSingleton('catalog/product_type_configurable') ->getChildrenIds($_product->getId());
```

**Then using those ids filter magento product collection also add custom attribute to collection**

```
$collection =Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection')->addAttributeToSelect('customattribute')->
               addAttributeToFilter('entity_id', array('in' =>  array_values($childIds[0])));
```

**Now filter those collection by in stock**

```
   $cond = array( '{{table}}.use_config_manage_stock = 0 AND {{table}}.manage_stock=1 AND {{table}}.is_in_stock=1', '{{table}}.use_config_manage_stock = 0 AND {{table}}.manage_stock=0', );

        $cond[] = '{{table}}.use_config_manage_stock = 1 AND {{table}}.is_in_stock=1';

    $collection->joinField(
        'inventory_in_stock',
        'cataloginventory/stock_item',
        'is_in_stock',
        'product_id=entity_id',
        '(' . join(') OR (', $cond) . ')'
    );
```

### Modified code:

```
<?php 
$_helper = $this->helper('catalog/output');
$_product = $this->getProduct();
$theme = $this->helper('royal');
$prods = $this->helper('egproducts');
$prodsConfig = $prods->getConfig('prev_next');
$prodId = $_product->getId();
$prevProduct = $prods->getPreviousProduct($prodId, $prodsConfig['list_sort_by'], $prodsConfig['list_sort_dir']);
$nextProduct = $prods->getNextProduct($prodId, $prodsConfig['list_sort_by'], $prodsConfig['list_sort_dir']);
$rightEnabled = $theme->getSetting('product_page/eg_right_column');
$gridClass = "grid-full no-padding";
if ($rightEnabled)
    $gridClass = "grid12-9 no-padding-left-lg no-padding-left-md no-padding-xs no-padding-sm grid-xs-full grid-sm-full";
?>
<?php
if($_product->getTypeId() == "configurable"): ?>
    <?php 
        $childIds=Mage::getResourceSingleton('catalog/product_type_configurable')
            ->getChildrenIds($_product->getId());
        $simple_collection=Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection')->
         addAttributeToFilter('entity_id', array('in' =>  array_values($childIds[0])))
         ->addAttributeToSelect('*')->addAttributeToSort('price', 'asc');   
                 // add  in stock to collection
        $cond = array(
            '{{table}}.use_config_manage_stock = 0 AND {{table}}.manage_stock=1 AND {{table}}.is_in_stock=1',
            '{{table}}.use_config_manage_stock = 0 AND {{table}}.manage_stock=0',
        );

            $cond[] = '{{table}}.use_config_manage_stock = 1 AND {{table}}.is_in_stock=1';

        $simple_collection->joinField(
            'inventory_in_stock',
            'cataloginventory/stock_item',
            'is_in_stock',
            'product_id=entity_id',
            '(' . join(') OR (', $cond) . ')'
        );


 ?>

<?php   foreach($simple_collection as $simple_product){ ?>
<div id="results">
<div class="mydata">
<table style="border-bottom: 1px solid #D3D3D3;">
some content
</table>
</div>
</div>
<?php
    }
endif;
?>
```

Comment: Thanks, can you show me where to implement this in the code I am using? Im a proper noob. Sorry :/

Comment: please show your existing cde..

Comment: Thats all I have and then under the code I have a table with code such as `<?php echo $simple_product->customattribute() ?>` which pulls this information from the simple product

Comment: Im ok with `$childIds=$_product->getTypeInstance()->getChildrenIds();` as i think I know where to put this, with my helpers right?

Comment: updated the answer..

Comment: I have added the complete file. If you could show your work in my file I would be hugely greatful :)

Comment: please check now

Comment: I got **Fatal error**: Call to a member function getUsedProductCollection() on a non-object in......

Comment: update please see.. there are mistake

Comment: You have helped me on more than one occasion. thank you so much.

Comment: Hey @Amit Bera thanks for your help on this script. I have a a problem.. When I enable flat product catalog, any custom attribute doesnt show. only default ones. Please help me :). doesnt matter! I just made the attribute visible on product listing and it worked